# Splitting condition for iteration method

Tags: linear-algebra

In iteration methods to solve $Ax = b$ we have the standard form as

$$M x^{(k+1)} = N x^{(k)} + b  \tag{$*$}$$

which $A = M - N$, and $M^{-1}N$ is called *iteration matrix*.

The standard convergence condition (for any iterative method) is when the spectral radius $\rho$ of the iteration matrix is less than 1.

> **Theorem:** Suppose $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=M-N \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is
>   nonsingular. If $M$ is non-singular and the spectral radius of
>   $M^{-1}N$ is less    than 1, then the iterates $x^{(k)}$ defined by
>   $(*)$ converge to $x=A^{-1}b$ for any starting vector $x^{(0)}$.

**Question is:**
Show that if $M-N$ is singular, then we can never have $\rho (M^{-1}N)<1$, even if $M$ is non-singular.

Comment: What's $\rho$? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: $\rho$ is spectral radius of a matrix.

I found this theorem: Let $M, N$ be a regular splitting of a matrix $A$. Then $\rho (M^{-1}N) < 1$ iff $A$ is non-singular and $A^{-1}$ is non-negative.

Comment: @wythagoras I edited ;) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\rho(M^{-1}N) < 1$. What can you say about the real eigenvalues of $I-M^{-1}N$?

Comment: $I - M^{-1}N$ is non-singular. Thanks for your hint.